# colorsync.display high cpu

Tags: kernel

[image]

PID 217, colorsync.display is pegged at 119% CPU, any ideas what this is or what might be causing it?

[image]

EDIT: It is happening again

[image]

EDIT EDIT (12/27/2019): Happening again with no cause known yet...

[image]

EDIT EDIT EDIT (2/2/2020): Happening again, any ideas?

There is no process in Activity Monitor showing that kind of CPU usage

[image]

[image]

[image]

Full log at https://gist.github.com/jeffreyroberts/22e88a32fe80af06e9aa31a6bdb5eea9

```
Analysis of sampling colorsync.displayservices (pid 214) every 1 millisecond
Process:         colorsync.displayservices [214]
Path:            /usr/libexec/colorsync.displayservices
Load Address:    0x10bcb6000
Identifier:      colorsync.displayservices
Version:         3345.6
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2019-12-08 23:54:17.509 -0500
Launch Time:     2019-12-07 21:38:19.656 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G1012)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /usr/bin/sample

Physical footprint:         11.7M
Physical footprint (peak):  11.8M
----

Call graph:
    2864 Thread_2260   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 2864 start  (in libdyld.dylib) + 1  [0x7fff666083d5]
    +   2864 ???  (in colorsync.displayservices)  load address 0x10bcb6000 + 0x3e28  [0x10bcb9e28]
    +     2864 CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 40  [0x7fff3a5e76b5]
    +       2864 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 459  [0x7fff3a5e78a5]
    +         2864 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 1619  [0x7fff3a5e814a]
    +           2864 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort  (in CoreFoundation) + 327  [0x7fff3a5e8bdd]
    +             2864 mach_msg  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 60  [0x7fff6673d76c]
    +               2864 mach_msg_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff6673d22a]
    2864 Thread_335454
      2864 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff667fb3fd]
        2864 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 458  [0x7fff667fb636]
          2864 __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff6673ebfe]

Total number in stack (recursive counted multiple, when >=5):

Sort by top of stack, same collapsed (when >= 5):
        __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        2864
        mach_msg_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        2864

Binary Images:
       0x10bcb6000 -        0x10bcbbfff  colorsync.displayservices (3345.6) <45FE7976-47D4-309F-96BC-F7C2C9C0DAB7> /usr/libexec/colorsync.displayservices
       0x119637000 -        0x1196a170f  dyld (655.1.1) <615654D5-B6C5-3D83-A146-34A3EA6D3A80> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff367a0000 -     0x7fff367a0fff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <B2A0C739-1D41-3452-9D00-8C01ADA5DD99> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff367b8000 -     0x7fff370acfcb  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - ???) <2905F53F-12C4-3583-A0A3-82607C5341CA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff370ad000 -     0x7fff37253feb  libBLAS.dylib (1243.200.4) <02059CCF-0B14-3BFA-9B74-B5685219682E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff37254000 -     0x7fff37298ff7  libBNNS.dylib (38.250.1) <AB890F6F-0B7D-3EC5-8A0E-874EAA4D0731> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
    0x7fff37299000 -     0x7fff37651ff3  libLAPACK.dylib (1243.200.4) <2CD8E9C6-E489-38E1-8A08-42CBE87FAC77> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff37652000 -     0x7fff37667ffb  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1243.200.4) <E7507B69-EF24-39D6-9B35-4A66E833C3F8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fff37668000 -     0x7fff3766dff3  libQuadrature.dylib (3.200.2) <1BAE7E22-2862-379F-B334-A3756067730F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libQuadrature.dylib
    0x7fff3766e000 -     0x7fff376eaff3  libSparse.dylib (79.200.5) <E78B33D3-672A-3C53-B512-D3DDB2E9AC8D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparse.dylib
    0x7fff376eb000 -     0x7fff376fdffb  libSparseBLAS.dylib (1243.200.4) <069BE0D3-FEDF-3848-81B7-B5D64F511EC6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff376fe000 -     0x7fff3789efef  libvDSP.dylib (671.250.4) <CA46FD92-D0CB-39B5-BD26-BEB3897D3154> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff3789f000 -     0x7fff37a13fdf  libvMisc.dylib (671.250.4) <9B4E3148-A73F-3DBF-A47B-68DAA26D15BE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff37a14000 -     0x7fff37a14fff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.11 - vecLib 3.11) <A83C1419-E651-3924-8A6D-FF7321C8AB90> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff389bd000 -     0x7fff389bdfff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (50.1 - 50.1) <3E60C239-ECEA-3AB8-B05C-1A66614E24F5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff389be000 -     0x7fff38a29fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS (377 - 453.11.2.2) <A258DA73-114B-3102-A056-4AAAD3CEB9DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff38ac2000 -     0x7fff38bd9fff  libFontParser.dylib (228.6.2.3) <3602D55B-3B9E-3B3A-A814-08C1244A8AE4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff38bda000 -     0x7fff38c1cfff  libFontRegistry.dylib (228.12.2.3) <2A56347B-2809-3407-A8B4-2AB88E484062> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff38d0d000 -     0x7fff38d11ff3  com.apple.ColorSyncLegacy (4.13.0 - 1) <AFC4FE0F-2F46-39E3-BF39-90AF0D4F63A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSyncLegacy.framework/Versions/A/ColorSyncLegacy
    0x7fff38dac000 -     0x7fff38dfeff7  com.apple.HIServices (1.22 - 628) <2BE461FF-80B9-30D3-A574-AED5724B1C1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff38dff000 -     0x7fff38e0efff  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0) <F5617A2A-FEA6-3832-B5BA-C2111B98786F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff38e0f000 -     0x7fff38e58ff7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (14.2 - 503.8) <57C2FE32-0E74-3079-B626-C2D52F2D2717> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff38e59000 -     0x7fff38e92ff7  com.apple.QD (3.12 - 407.2) <28C7D39F-59C9-3314-BECC-67045487229C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff38e93000 -     0x7fff38e9ffff  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework (8.1.3 - 8.1.3) <5E7B9BD4-122B-3012-A044-3259C97E7509> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff38ea0000 -     0x7fff39117fff  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.14 - 1.14) <571A3B68-AB1D-3050-932A-999EA148963C> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff39472000 -     0x7fff39813fff  com.apple.CFNetwork (978.1 - 978.1) <01AB9E36-3C9F-3070-8D46-7F14B99A757A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff39d38000 -     0x7fff39e87ff7  com.apple.ColorSync (4.13.0 - 3345.6) <F47177B2-7113-3642-98A5-602819CD02B0> /System/Library/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff3a013000 -     0x7fff3a099fff  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio (4.3.0 - 4.3.0) <1E8E64E6-0E58-375A-97F7-07CB4EE181AC> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fff3a128000 -     0x7fff3a4bbff3  com.apple.CoreData (120 - 866.6) <2408A361-E56E-30AD-B8CF-94305552E86C> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
    0x7fff3a4bc000 -     0x7fff3a5acff7  com.apple.CoreDisplay (101.3 - 110.18) <BA4092D7-27D3-3886-ABC0-74CDCF747350> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreDisplay.framework/Versions/A/CoreDisplay
    0x7fff3a5ad000 -     0x7fff3a9f3ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1575.23) <817EE1C1-B814-38C0-A569-4B2ECCE36DB6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff3a9f5000 -     0x7fff3b0a1ff7  com.apple.CoreGraphics (2.0 - 1265.10) <06969FBB-0809-3D8B-B0B7-AF00D42F0957> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff3b0a3000 -     0x7fff3b3c3fff  com.apple.CoreImage (14.4.0 - 750.0.140) <11026E39-D2FF-3CF6-8ACE-7BA293F9853E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage
    0x7fff3b821000 -     0x7fff3b821fff  com.apple.CoreServices (946 - 946) <9A402CC6-8163-3CF1-8670-B95796B1A0EE> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff3b822000 -     0x7fff3b89eff7  com.apple.AE (773 - 773) <55AE7C9E-27C3-30E9-A047-3B92A6FD53B4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff3b89f000 -     0x7fff3bb76fff  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1178.33 - 1178.33) <CB87F0C7-2CD6-3983-8E32-B6A2EC925352> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff3bb77000 -     0x7fff3bbbfff7  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 284.16.4) <746EB200-DC51-30AE-9CBC-608A7B4CC8DA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff3bbc0000 -     0x7fff3bbc8ffb  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1239.200.13 - 1239.200.13) <28BF3EC6-9985-3402-AEA9-0FF6EE1C200E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fff3bbc9000 -     0x7fff3bd7aff7  com.apple.LaunchServices (946 - 946) <A0C91634-9410-38E8-BC11-7A5A369E6BA5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff3bd7b000 -     0x7fff3be19ff7  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 1191.57) <BFFAED00-2560-318A-BB8F-4E7E5123EC61> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff3be1a000 -     0x7fff3be64ff7  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (946 - 946) <20C4EEF8-D5AC-39A0-9B4A-78F88E3EFBCC> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff3be65000 -     0x7fff3beccff7  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <DA08AA6F-A6F1-36C0-87F4-E26294E51A3A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff3becd000 -     0x7fff3beeeff3  com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList (71.28 - 71.28) <487A8464-729E-305A-B5D1-E3FE8EB9CFC5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SharedFileList.framework/Versions/A/SharedFileList
```

Comment: Was the sample taken when it was running high? The screenshot shows 0.0 CPU%. Colorsync is part of MacOS's graphics system that ensure accurate or consistent colors. Why it's pegging a core is unknown here.

Comment: That is just it, In `htop` or `top` it shows a pegged core, in activity monitor, 0%

Comment: What computer are you using this with? Do you have Night Shift or True Tone enabled?

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same today on a 2019 13-inch MacBook Pro. I only saw the process in `htop` with high CPU usage stuck at the same value for several minutes, but not showing in Activity Monitor. I quit and started `htop` again and it appears to be gone. If I filter for `colorsync` it shows a number of processes, among them `colorsync.display`, with CPU usage at 0%.

[image: htop output filtered for “colorsync”]

This may just be a process that gets stuck in `htop` for some reason.

**Update 24th of February 2021:** experienced the same on a M1 MacBook Air. Restarting `htop` removed it from the top CPU-consuming processes listed there.

Comment: The same happened to me. After rerunning `htop` the process with name `colorsync.displa` disappeared.

Comment: This looks like an `htop` bug - same issue and workaround on macOS 10.13

Comment: I'm experiencing the issue, and in my case, the high CPU usage is reported by both Activity Monitor, and iStat Menus.

Comment: @Cykelero is it persistent or does it disappear when restarting Activity Monitor or iStat Menus?

Comment: @dniviE Definitely persistent—restarting the apps doesn't make it go away. top reports it too. In my case, the issue seems triggered by specific apps. (Nova and Sketch)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Activity Monitor, you can select the process and **Inspect Process** <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>. The click on the "Open Files and Ports" tab.

That will show you all the files that the process is using, but the most relevant files should be at the top of the list.